# C# regex expression for allowing spaces but not at the beginning, end and repeated spaces

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I have a regex expression validation for an UI field:

```
^[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_|\-]+$
```

Now I need to allow spaces for the entry, so if I add space to the regex expression, like this:

```
^[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_| |\-]+$
```

It does allow spaces at the beginning, end and repeated spaces.

Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to remove the `|` symbol from the character class and also include `\s` instead of a whitespace.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$"
```

But `\s` matches newline characters also. So change `\s` to a whitespace in the above regex based upon your needs. The main thing here is the non-capturing group `(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*` which matches,

- a space `\s` and also the following one or more word or hyphen characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`, zero or more times `(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oR0dL2/1)

Comment: Ok will do, but that does not fix accepting spaces at the start and the end.

Comment: no, it won't accept spaces at the beginning or at the end. See the demo link.